# AJAX POST in .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I have the below javascript AJAX request which works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: requestUrl,
    data: {
        var1: 'value1',
        var2: 'value2',
        var3: 'value3'
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
        if (jqXhr !== undefined && jqXhr !== null && jqXhr.statusText === "OK") {
            alert("Request Success" + jqXhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Request Failed" + (jqXhr.responseText || textStatus));
        }

    }
});
```

I would like to do the same using .NET.

I tried the following:

```
string result = string.Empty;
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");

        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["var1"] = "value1";
        values["var2"] = "value2";
        values["var3"] = "value3";

        var response = client.UploadValues(requestUrl, values);

        result = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error=" + exception.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine("result=" + result);
```

However I get an Internal Server Error.

How do I recreate a cross domain request? Is there a specific header to set?

WebException details:

Response: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
Headers:
Persistent-Auth: true
Content-Length: 5143
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 12:03:21 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Comment: What does the server error say?

Comment: I do not have access to the server. It is a service hosted by another development team.

Comment: Try the service manually using a tool like Fiddler2 to create the request and see what the server will actually accept.

Comment: Or you can setup a `error` handler in the `$.ajax` request and check the properties it returns. Either way, you can't solve anything without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I have Fiddler2 and I can see the request go through in AJAX. What headers should I look out for?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - The AJAX request is successful

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, considering you state that the server returns a 500 error code...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - The error is only relevant to the .NET code and not the javascript code

Comment: If would help to show us the response text.  Cast the exception to a WebException, and then get the Response property.  Get the response text from that.

Comment: If it's a 500, then I would suggest to tell the development team to fix their code.  It should return 4xx for an invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error it's hard to say exactly what's going on but if you suspect this is a CORS issue then you can add these headers:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        Prop1 = 1,
        Prop2 = "data 2"
    });

using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
{
    client.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-origin", "*");
    client.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    client.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-headers", "Authorization, content-type, accept");
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.UploadData("your url", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. Fiddler for the .NET code showed two 401 before the 500. The credentials did not seem to go through: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Comment: Do you know what type of authentication the server is using (basic, bearer token, etc)? The way you are sending the credentials you are using basic auth, but the server you are contacting may require more than that. Also in your ajax code you are sending json but in your C# code you are sending name value pairs. Make sure you send a json object and add this to the headers: "Content-Type", "application/json".

Comment: I tried sending the data as JSON and setting the content type as "application/json" but I got the same error. The IIS server hosted website has windows authentication enabled.

Comment: Since this is windows auth try this: client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; Or in your using statement: using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })

Comment: Tried DefaultCredentials and got the same error. I have updated the error and headers in the question

Comment: Your problem is here: Content-Type: text/html; Your header needs to specify the content type of json if that is what is expected. See my edit above.